# Python/Tkinter : update class variable with a button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is probably a silly question, but I couldn't find an answer to it on here, so here goes.

I'm setting up a Tkinter interface, and I'm only one button in. This button, when clicked should change the variable `go` to `1`, I have done this by requiring it to call the function `getGo(self)` which is in the same class as the `init` function where the button was set up.

My problem is that it doesn't run the whole `goTime()` function: ie, it doesn't update my variable `go`.

`init` function:

```
class New_Toplevel_1:
    go=0
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        self.butGo = Button(top,command=lambda *args: goTime(self))
        self.butGo.place(relx=0.48, rely=0.84, height=41, width=65)
        self.butGo.configure(activebackground="#7bd93b")
        self.butGo.configure(font=font12)
        self.butGo.configure(text='''Go!''')

    def goTime(self):
        print("It's go time!")
        self.go=1
        print("go has been updated")
```

The output looks like this (repeated the number of times I clicked the button):

```
It's go time!
It's go time!
It's go time!
It's go time!
```

Why won't it update the variable? Or even show "`go has been updated`"?
Thanks!

Comment: when you originally define go, define it as self.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `command` argument incorrectly, just do:

```
self.butGo = Button(top, command=self.goTime)
```

To reference an instance method / attribute you must do `self.method_name` (`self` is just a convention)

If you need to pass arguments, you can use lambda:

```
command=lambda: self.go_time(5)
command=lambda n: self.go_time(n)
...
```

although I prefer `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

class NewToplevel1:
    go = 0

    def __init__(self, top=None):
        self.butGo = Button(top, command=partial(self.go_time, 5))
        self.butGo.place(relx=0.48, rely=0.84, height=41, width=65)
        self.butGo.configure(activebackground="#7bd93b")

        self.butGo.configure(text='''Go!''')

    def go_time(self, n):
        print("It's go time!")
        self.go = n
        print("go has been updated")
        print(self.go)
```